# SQL Server Mgmt Studio for SQL Server 2008 R2 says .Net is 2.0?

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server Mgmt Studio with SQL Server 2008 R2. Was having trouble running known a good SQL query from php code (just would not run, no errors reported). After checking, only thing found amiss was `SSMS > Help > About` says:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio        10.50.6000.34
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)       3.85.1132
Microsoft MSXML                               2.6 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                   8.0.6001.18702
Microsoft .NET Framework                      2.0.50727.3655
Operating System                              5.1.2600
```

The reported .Net Framework value is too low. This machine has .Net 2.0, 3.5-sp1, 4.0 installed.  The web articles I read said to run Server Manager, click Features Tab, enable the .Net 3.5 sp1.  But Win XP does not seem to have a Service Manager, the Adminpak.msi for XP did not have it, and the Windows Power Shell is 32bit and could not import the Service Manager module.

Please advise.

Comment: You cannot disable/enable different .NET Framework versions in Windows XP; you can only install or uninstall them. Server Manager applies to Windows Server only. In addition, it is not clear what issue you are having. May need to clarify further.

Comment: This is the version of the **built-in SQL CLR** runtime - the .NET Framework that's built into SQL Server core. SQL Server 2005 through 2008 R2 used .NET 2.0, and as of SQL Server 2012, it's .NET 4.0. This has nothing to do with the .NET framework(s) installed on your machine per se - it's the **SQL Server internal** SQL CLR .NET runtime version

Comment: Thank you.  It is a Win XP system.  I carefully installed PHP 5.3 and the drivers (php_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll, php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll).  They do show up in phpinfo().  But all sql queries from php code just do not run.  I do not know why.

Comment: "code just does not run, no errors reported". You need to get to the bottom of this. By 'not run' do you mean never returns? returns no rows? This is a very vague error message and I see no reason to start thinking it has anything to do with the SQL Server. One step you can take is use SQL Profiler to see what is being submitted to the server

Comment: Nick:  Your earlier efforts on the other post question enabled the queries to run now.  Your suggestion fixed the malformed query string. At your convenience, you may want to consider the Answer posted below about the .Net Framework.  Ken

Answer (score 0):

In the weeks since this question was originally posted, some 
additional understandings have surfaced.

The comments said:

> "This is the version of the built-in SQL CLR  runtime - the .NET
>   Framework that's built into SQL Server core.   SQL Server 2005 through
>   2008 R2 used .NET 2.0,...".

So for my SQL Server Express 2008 R2 installation the following is 
considered correct:

> SSMS > Help > About
>   Microsoft .NET Framework         2.0.50727.3655

One additional new understanding is that (contrary to the comments) there does appear to be a way to affect (enable/disable) the referenced installed .Net Framework versions (on windows XP SP3).

Consider the following file:
C:\Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Application Data\
Microsoft_Corporation\LandingPage.exe_StrongName_ryspccglaxmt4nhllj5z3
thycltsvyyx\
10.0.0.0\user.config

(where line 3) says:
  System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0

(where line 4) says:
  System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0

These version entries were written by the mssql installer and are strongly suspected (although not proven) to be referring to the (highest) installed .Net Framework package (on that machine).
To support that statement please consider the following URL reference.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d4d657bd-8212-4287-b5ed-e6055cbceb09/config-error-refers-to-version-4000-after-retargeting-to-2000-even-after-changing-all?forum=netfxbcl

(This user did not experience any of the problems discussed in that URL but cited it as reference only to support the suspected association between the version in user.config and the installed .Net Framework version.)

Circumstances for this user required more than one installation attempt of mssql server.  On an earlier attempt, the mssql installer wrote version 2.0... into the user.config file (which was quickly discarded).  On a later attempt, the mssql installer wrote version 4.0... into the user.config file (on the same machine, which was accepted).  Notice the version written by the installer was not the same in both installation instances and is difficult to explain.  (This user ultimately went with version 4.0....)

A second additional understanding is that the presence (existence) of a user.config file (in that exact path location) from an earlier mssql installation causes the ms sql server express 2008 R2 installation to halt twice on error (at begin, and at end) and ask for user permission to continue.  Continuing produced an acceptable installation.  But most commentators seem to recommend deleting that user.config file remnant from the earlier installation ahead of the new install and just let the mssql installer recreate it.  (Although any user.config file referencing less than v4.0... was not accepted by this user.)

By the way, after extensive investigation, the root problem which propted this post question (in the first place) proved unrelated to the .Net Framework version (at all) and instead was the direct result of a malformed query string.